# how to connect with ssh when it's hanging

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to ssh into a remote machine, but it hangs when looking for an identity file:

```
[username@local .ssh]$ ssh -v remote uname
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote [192.168.3.36] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
```

I can ping the machine normally, and it's obviously working with the sshd service running... I just don't know how to log into it. In fact, I'd just like to reboot it. That'd be fine. Thing is: it's across the ocean (I'm in the US, and the machine is in Europe). I'd run some hundreds of java threads at the same time and apparently that was too much for the host.

How can I get back in?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find some way that does not involve `ssh`.

Call someone on the phone who can physically reboot it.  Hopefully there is some support staff there?

Servers often have some kind of management interface outside of the operating system that allows for reboot over the network, useful for when this type of situation happens.